# How do I get selected item from a JqxListBox?

Tags: javascript

How do I get selected item from a JqxListBox? When I click on list item it should alert me selected item but instead it returns undefined.
 thx!

my code:

```
function onS() {
    var listString = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    var listEnumerator = list.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {

        var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listString[i] = "<br/>" + currentItem.get_title();
        i++;

    }
    $("#jqxWidget").jqxListBox({ source: listString, width: '300px', height: '400px' });

} 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jqxWidget').click( function() {

        var selectedItem = $("#jqxWidget option:selected").last();
        alert("SelectedItem Text: " + selectedItem.html());
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxlistbox/jquery-listbox-api.htm), It should be

```
var selectedIndex = $('#jqxWidget').jqxListBox('selectedIndex');
```

For [multi-select](http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-selected-items/)

```
// get all items.
var items = $("#jqxWidget").jqxListBox('getItems');
// get selected indexes.
var selectedIndexes = $("#jqxWidget").jqxListBox('selectedIndexes');
var selectedItems = [];
// get selected items.
for (var index in selectedIndexes) {
    if (selectedIndexes[index] != -1) {
        selectedItems[index] = items[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: thx but this is returning index not text. I want it to return text.

Comment: use `var item = $("#jqxListBox").jqxListBox('getItem', 1 ); ` and also read the documentation. `1` is the item index.